# Can't install port that is visible on macports.org [Macports]

Tags: macports, language, package-management

I've been trying to get some of my packages from Homebrew moved to Macports recently. One such package was the [Crystal programming language.](https://crystal-lang.org/) Unfortunately, `sudo port install crystal` doesn't work:

```
$ sudo port install crystal
Error: Port crystal not found
```

Likewise, `port info` and `port search` yield no info about the Crystal language:

```
$ port info crystal
Error: Port crystal not found
$ port search crystal
crystfel @0.6.1_6 (science)
    A suite of programs for processing serial crystallography data

gnome-chemistry-utils @0.14.17 (gnome, science, chemistry)
    This package provides a set of Gtk3-based applications for drawing and viewing molecules, crystals and spectra.

gpp4 @1.3.1_1 (science)
    macromolecular crystallography library

xcrysden @1.5.60_2 (science)
    X-windows CRYstalline Structures and DENsities

Found 4 ports.
```

Yet, when I search [macports.org](https://www.macports.org/) for `crystal`, I see it:

[image]

[Here's the search URL.](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=crystal)

What's going on? Why can't I install Crystal, yet I can see it on the website?

Comment: Have you tried updating Mac Ports with `sudo port selfupdate`?

Comment: @Josh Doh! That did the trick. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I have added my answer. Additionally, can you please edit your question title to be more broad as it may allow others to find the solution easier even if they are not looking for Crystal.

Comment: @Josh I changed the title as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating Mac Ports using the command `sudo port selfupdate`. You can read more about updating and installing Mac Ports [here](https://www.macports.org/install.php).